# Remove mentions and special characters for twitter dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am trying to remove from this dataframe the mentions and special characters as "!?$..." and especially the character "#" but keeping the text of the hashtag.

Something like this is what I would like to have:

```
tweet                                          clean_tweet
---------------------------------------------|-----------
"This is an example @user2 #Science ! #Tech" | "This is an example Science Tech"
"Hi How are you @user45 #USA"                | "Hi How are you USA"
```

I am not sure how to iterate and do this in my dataframe in the column tweet
I tried with this for special characters

```
df["clean_tweet"] = df.columns.str.replace('[#,@,&]', '')
```

But I have this error

```
ValueError: Length of values (38) does not match length of index (82702)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to process column names

try this

```
df["clean_tweet"] = df["tweet"].str.replace('[#,@,&]', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you want to remove @user.So I used regex here

```py
df['clean_tweet'] = df['tweet'].replace(regex='(@\w+)|#|&|!',value='')
```

```
    tweet                                       clean_tweet
0   This is an example @user2 #Science ! #Tech  This is an example Science Tech
1   Hi How are you @user45 #USA                 Hi How are you USA
```